# Cannot send emails to gmail accounts using SMTP

Tags: python, email, smtp, gmail

I have recently tried making an email bot with Python. The idea of the bot is you send an email with a specific message to an email and it returns an image. Here is the code I wrote:

```py
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage

from redbox import EmailBox

username = 'begichal66@gmail.com'
password = 'example password'
server = 'imap.gmail.com'
port = 993

box = EmailBox(
    username=username,
    password=password,
    host=server,
    port=port
)

inbox = box['INBOX']

name = "Kompot"
wanted_msg = "купон"

while True:
    to_answer = []

    for msg in inbox.search(unseen=True):
        msg_body = msg.text_body.strip().lower()

        if msg_body == wanted_msg:
            to_answer.append(msg.from_)

    for sender in to_answer:
        EMAIL = MIMEMultipart()
        EMAIL['From'] = name
        EMAIL['To'] = sender
        EMAIL['Subject'] = "Твоят купон"

        with open("image.png", 'rb') as f:
            img_data = f.read()
            EMAIL.attach(MIMEImage(img_data, name="image.png"))

        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as server:
            server.starttls(context=context)
            server.login(username, password)
            server.sendmail(name, sender, EMAIL.as_string())
            server.quit()
```

It works well for the 'abv.bg' domain, but the problem I'm having is that it doesn't respond to 'gmail.com' accounts. It only responds to 'abv.bg' (although I haven't tested it for other domains). The email receives it and even reads it (I know this, because I sort by unread and it makes the email read). But it just doesn't send it, I even checked the 'Sent' category. No emails sent to 'gmail.com' accounts.

Comment: Are you using your standard password or have you created a specific app password for this program?

Comment: I cannot use my standard password for this. I am using an app password from my google account.